# Can we apply image filters on new fabric.Image()?

Tags: fabricjs

I wish to apply an image filter on a fabric.Image object but I am unable to do so.

Here is my code:

**(Approach: 1) Create an image and add to canvas**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var img = document.querySelector('.images img.img_dragging');
var newImg = new fabric.Image(img, {
                        scaleX: .50,
                        scaleY:.50,
                     });
newImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite({ threshold:10 ,distance: 100 }));
newImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.add(newImg);
```

**Html** (Image src is just a random image from net, but our project images are somewhat similar)

```
<img draggable="true" src="http://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/blue-small-tufted-sofa.jpg" width="250" height="250"></img>
```

*With above I am able to add the image to the canvas and maneuver the image on the canvas.*

My requirement is to remove the extra white spaces from the background of the above image.

As per my reading over net we can implement the above like:

**(Approach: 2)**:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/blue-small-tufted-sofa.jpg', function(img){                
     img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite({ threshold:10 ,distance: 100 }));
     img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
     img.scale(0.5);
     canvas.add(img);           
});
```

So I wish to seek whether I can use filters with approach 1 and if there is a snippet on how to implement it. 
Or filters can only we applied to fromURL approach only.

Any pointers would be a great help.

Cheers!
AJ

P.S : Apologies for any typos.

Comment: In both cases, You are trying to add an cross origin image to the canvas for that you need to add the `crossOrigin` option. But however the image you are trying to load does not support cross origin access so you can't load the image to canvas.

Comment: @Kesavan the problem is not only cross origin. filters don't work well on images added with `fabric.Image`. It makes the images blurry after the filter is applied. 
The only solution I found is to use `fabric.Image.fromURL` which is not an option for me as it's slow for my application.